# Angularjs version 1.5 select statement not showing selected value on refresh

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm wondering why a string when used as the value in a <\select> tag (not ng-select) will load the saved drop down value on a page refresh but an integer will not display a value. Assuming that formData.maritalStatus equals "Married" or "1" depending on the example value below.

```html
This works when formData.maritalStatus = "Married"
                        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="maritalStatus">Marital Status</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <select class="form-control" name="maritalStatus"
                                        ng-model="formData.maritalStatus">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value="Married">Married</option>
                                    <option value="Single">Single</option>
                                    <option value="Divorced">Divorced</option>
                                    <option value="Widowed">Widowed</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
​
This does not work when formData.maritalStatus = "1"
​
                        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="maritalStatus">Marital Status</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <select class="form-control" name="maritalStatus"
                                        ng-model="formData.maritalStatus">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value="1">Married</option>
                                    <option value="2">Single</option>
                                    <option value="3">Divorced</option>
                                    <option value="4">Widowed</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

This is purely educational as the string works for my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this does not natively work with older versions of AngularJS. AngularJS 1.6.x and above will work work using the ng-value directive (this will give you what you are looking for).

```
<option ng-value="1">Married</option>
```

However, there is a solution that can be found in the AngularJS Docs that essentially uses a parser and formatter. The formatter converts the int-to-string when the model changes and the parser does the opposite (string-to-int).

https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/api/ng/directive/select#binding-select-to-a-non-string-value-via-ngmodel-parsing-formatting

Take a look at the link above to view the solution for apps using anything before 1.6.x (taken directly from the AngularJS Documentation). If you haven't taken a look already, I think you could also benefit from using ng-options. It is used to for dynamic lists instead of hardcoded options.

Take a look if you'd like!
https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/docs/api/ng/directive/ngOptions